# Creating a sub subclass with java

Tags: java, subclass

[image: Directed UML]

I was directed to create a class Vehicle with three subclasses [RaceCar, Car and Truck] and then put a subclass into Car, like shown in the UML.

But when I try to do this by saying

```
public class HybridCar extends Car
```

I get an error. I know that in java I can't double inherit so how do I format the HybridCar Constructor?

here is my `Car` class.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{ 
   double luggageCap; 
   double passengerCap; 

   public Car(String make, String model, double engSz, String id, String year, String color, double lugCap, double passCap){ 
      super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color); 
      luggageCap = lugCap; 
      passengerCap = passCap; 
   } 

   public double getLuggageCap(){
      return luggageCap; 
   } 

   public double getPassengerCap(){
      return passengerCap; 
   } 

   public String toString(){ 
      return super.toString()+", "+luggageCap+", "+passengerCap; 
   } 
}
```

here is my `HybridCar` class:

```
public class HybridCar extends Car{
   double luggageCap;
   double passengerCap; 
   double batteryCap; 

   public HybridCar(String make, String model, double engSz, String id,    String year, String color, double lugCap, double passCap, double batCap){
      super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color); 
      luggageCap = lugCap; 
      passengerCap = passCap;
      batteryCap = batCap; 
   }    

   public String toString(){
      return super.toString()+", "+luggageCap+", "+passengerCap+", "+batteryCap; 
   } 

}
```

here is the error log:

> HybridCar.java:9: error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be
>   applied to given types; super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color); ^
>   required: String,String,double,String,String,String,double,double
>   found: String,String,double,String,String,String reason: actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length 1 error –

Comment: 1) what does the error say?  2) can you show your code for the HybridCar class? 3) " I know that in java I can't double inherit " if HybridCar only inherits Car then that is not an issue, so where does double inherit come from?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Maybe you just forgot to put curly braces?

Comment: public class HybridCar extends Car{

  double luggageCap;
  double passengerCap;
  double batteryCap;

  public HybridCar(String make, String model, double engSz, String id, String year, String color, double lugCap, double passCap, double batCap){
    super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color);
    luggageCap = lugCap;
    passengerCap = passCap;
    batteryCap = batCap;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
  return super.toString()+", "+luggageCap+", "+passengerCap+", "+batteryCap;
  }
}

Comment: And again, what was the exact error you got? Inquiring minds want to know!

Comment: @jdogg can you post the Car class code aswell ? Also,  can you state the error you're currently getting?

Comment: HybridCar.java:9: error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;
    super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color);
    ^
  required: String,String,double,String,String,String,double,double
  found: String,String,double,String,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: public class Car extends Vehicle{

  double luggageCap;
  double passengerCap;
  
  public Car(String make, String model, double engSz, String id, String year, String color, double lugCap, double passCap){
    super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color);
    luggageCap = lugCap;
    passengerCap = passCap;
  }
  

  public double getLuggageCap(){
  return luggageCap;
  }
  
  public double getPassengerCap(){
  return passengerCap;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+", "+luggageCap+", "+passengerCap;
  }
  
 }

Comment: Sorry about the formatting

Comment: @jdogg unfortunately I can no longer consider this question because I have edited your question with the given code but yet you erased the edit and rather preferred to write your code within the comments.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw that was my mistake. First time posting on here, usually I can find the answer quickly in old posts

Comment: @jdogg no problem.

Comment: @jdogg see my answer to your question.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;
>   super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color); ^ required:
>   String,String,double,String,String,String,double,double found:
>   String,String,double,String,String,String reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length 1 error

if you look carefully at the `Car` constructor there are 8 parameters of certain types:

```
Car(String make, String model, double engSz, String id, String year, String color, double lugCap, double passCap)
```

However, you're only passing in 6 parameters:

```
super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color);
```

The issue seems to be that you're not passing in the required parameters to the `Car` constructor.

change your `HybribCar` constructor to this:

```
super(make, model, engSz, id, year, color,lugCap, passCap);
```

**side note** -  ensure that you're passing the right number of parameters to each class constructor and also ensure the types for each parameter match.